# how do I include a file more than two folders back

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have written a piece of code but I have come across an issue, my config.json folder is not found. in case it's needed the format is
/commands/music

`const { YOUTUBE_API_KEY, SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID } = require(".../config.json");`

the error is
`Error: cannot find module '.../config.json'`

I would appreciate it if someone helps me out here

Comment: "../../file" probably something like that or any further extension of ../

Comment: @woblob you were right, it worked just right. I'm sorry for asking such a silly question, I'm new to coding